# Trying to create a stored procedure with error capturing that would print error upon execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help with creating a stored procedure. What I am trying to do is validate count between source and target table, upon executing stored procedure I need print that would say "there is miscount btwn source and target table. However I am not getting print message that I need, please see my code below and if you could let me know where error is in my code? FYI, this is my first attempt to automate some of my scripts as QA (for ETL). Please go easy on me :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ##accountDB_count
AS
    BEGIN TRY

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##error_count;

    CREATE TABLE ##error_count
    ( 
         [object] varchar(255),
         source_count integer
    );

    WIT cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
         'Data Migration source count' as [object]
         ,count(distinct s.account_id) as count_all
       FROM MariaDBMigration.infoarmor_secure.subscribers s
       INNER JOIN MariaDBMigration.infoarmor_secure.subscribers_accounts sa ON s.account_id = sa.id
       INNER JOIN MariaDBMigration.infoarmor_secure.subscribers_accounts_plan sap ON sa.account_type 
       = sap.id
       INNER JOIN migration.dbo.map_subscriber_four_fields map on map.subscriber_id = s.id
       WHERE s.customerid in (3444,3497,4662,4663,3958,3959,4549,4550,4655)
         AND s.active = 1 --OR ( (DATEADD(DAY, 90,  coalesce(canceled_date, getdate() )))  > 
         GETDATE() ) )
         AND S.is_primary =1
    )
    ,cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT 'ACCOUNT_target count' AS [object], COUNT(*) AS count_all 
        FROM account.dbo.account
    )
    ,cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM cte
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM cte1
        UNION
        SELECT 
            'differance' AS [object],
            (SELECT count_all FROM cte) - (SELECT count_all FROM cte1)
    )
    INSERT INTO ##error_count
        SELECT * FROM CTE2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @COUNT_ALL INT = 0;
    WHILE @COUNT_ALL != (SELECT * FROM ##error_count WHERE [object] = 'differance')
    begin 
    PRINT 'MISSCOUNT'
    end
END CATCH
```

Comment: The `PRINT` will only the reached if you get an error, and then if it tries to `PRINT`, it'll error as `##error_count` has 2 columns, you use `*` and a subquery must return a scalar value when used in that context. And *even* if it didn't error, it would then infinitely `PRINT` the value `'MISSCOUNT'` if the subquery returned the scalar value `0`.

Comment: Honestly, you need to take a step back and explain your real goal here. It's not working, because there are several errors, and you will only `PRINT` on the event of an error, and I *assume* you aren't getting an error.

Comment: In first portion I have cte code where I am counting records from the source, cte1 I am counting records in target table, cte2 I am using union statement to bring all results together, then inserting into temp table ##error_count, from there I am declaring variable @COUNT_ALL and setting to '0', using that as condition if difference in count is 0 then there is no miscount if is then I need to get message miscount printed. I hope this helps.

Comment: Then why is that in the `CATCH`?

Comment: Where it should be? I am first time trying to create something like this so not sure where it should be.

Comment: And why do you not `THROW` the error when you are in the `CATCH`? Why is it set up to infinitely loop if the `PRINT` *could* be reached?

Comment: Do you not understand what a [`TRY...CATCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`WHILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  does? Such syntax isn't unique to SQL Server; they are pretty standard to any language (not just SQL).

Comment: I believe I shouldn't be using while, but where to place condition to validate count and where print statement should be?

Comment: *Not* in the `CATCH`; that's for handling errors in.

Comment: So I should remove CATCH completely ?

Comment: This is a completely wrong use of `TRY-CATCH`, what you need is [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you guys, I have removed begin catch, used if condition and print statement and it worked, thx again for leading me through this. I have another question, if I want add another temp table  to list all records that are missing in target table where that would be added, after code where is print or before?

Comment: If you have a new question, @DKCroat, post a new question.

Comment: Thank you, will do!